# Encapsulation vs returning by pointer in large C++ objects

Tags: c++, oop, graph-theory, encapsulation

I have a a design problem, which boils down to the fact that I don't really understand encapsulation. Consider the untested C++ code, which might contain bugs:

```
class Graph{
private:
   map<int, Vertex*> mapVertexIdToVertexPointer;
public:
   Vertex* findVertexById(int id){
      return mapVertexIdToVertexPointer.find(id)->second;
   }
   void getAllVertexPtrs(set<Vertex*>& setVertices){
      for(const auto& it : mapVertexIdToVertexPointer)
      {
           setVertices.insert(it.second);
      }
   }
}
```

The reason why I resort to the pointers is because each `vertex` might be a large object (say each vertex is adjacent to 10000 other vertices or each contains some large data such as 1MB of picture of people's portraits).

1) On one hand, I think this is bad encapsulation in the sense that outer objects can modify the vertices and its data and in turn modify the graphs since the vertices are just component of the graphs.

2) On another hand, I can also argue that what the Graph object really tries to hide is how it implements its collection of vertices i.e. via a map. As long as we keep the graph's API consistent and not return this map as pointer (so either return a pointer if require returning individual vertices or return a set if require all vertices), the purpose of making the map private is served.

Which of these argument/definition of encapsulation is correct?

What is the best practice to return object if your object contains several large objects?

Assuming the application should be fast to process many vertices.

NOTE DUE TO SIDE TRACK DISCUSSION: The main question is what is encapsulation, and how the code above violates/unviolate this principle and NOT about how to implement the code regarding memory, choice of library, syntax ... since it is made up on the spot without thorough consideration.

Comment: What should be encapsulated is a design decision. You cannot fault `std::vector` for allowing access to its objects, because hiding its objects is the opposite of the design goal. Hiding memory management is. Without a design goal you cannot answer those questions.

Comment: uhmn... thanks, @nwp. Would it then be correct to say encapsulation can be a relative concept i.e. depending on what design decision define what to encapsulate then?

Comment: Maybe "design decision" is the wrong term. "External requirements" would be better. The users of your program or library might be required to store, explore and manipulate graphs (in the mathematical sense) with low overhead in memory/CPU/learning for typical use cases. So that is what you should give them. Personally I would try to allow users to just access the map. It gives users a lot of power. Unless you can't do that because it would make it too easy to screw up invariants of `Graph`, in which case try to get as close as possible (return const_iterator pairs?).

Comment: To extend @nwp's point `Graph::findVertexById` is basically `map::operator[]` (but with the potential for UB) and `Graph::getAllVertexPtrs` could be replaced with something like Boost's [`boost::adaptors::map_values`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html) applied to `mapVertexIdToVertexPointer`, or similar.

Comment: thanks @Caleth... sorry for the bad code, I was trying to understand encapsulation, and made it up from memory. `map_values` might not be the best choice as I have never used boost, I probably would go with `transform` and lambda functions, but can't recall the syntax.

Comment: @Tuan333 the point of returning the boost range is that it can be used anywhere that accepts a `begin, end` pair of iterators, passing through to the map's iterators

Comment: So is transform, maybe?

Comment: As alternative to return objects, you might add method to apply function to object: `void apply_to_each_vertex(std::function<void (const Vertex&)>);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some way to improve the design.

First, you can define an "interface" or a proxy that give only read-only access to the data or simply return `const` objects. Which option to select really depends on what you want to be able to do, the possible performance impact and the degree of protection against changes you need.

Second, you can use smart pointers to ensure that vertexes won't be destroyed when they are removed from the map if they are any external reference to them.

Assuming single threaded-code, you could change the map declaration to:

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Vertex>> mapVertexIdToVertexPointer;
```

Assuming that `const` protection is enough, you can change your function to:

```
std::shared_ptr<const Vertex> findVertexById(int id);
void getAllVertexPtrs(std::set<shared_ptr<Vertex>>& setVertices);
```

I am not sure if you need to redefine comparison in this case... It is **suspicious** that you returns a `set` of pointers. Maybe you want to ensure they are unique... Also, do you want to allows modification of the returned `set`. If not, then returning iterators instead would give better encapsulation.

Instead, as an alternative, you might consider having a function that take a function to apply for each vertex. Something like:

```
void forEachVertex(std::func<const Vertex &> fnToApply);
```

Or if the code is trivial and you want the best performance, you might prefer

```
template <class F>
void forEachVertex(F fnToApply);
```

Or if `virtual` function overhead is acceptable and you have a lot of external operation, an abstract class might be a good solution to:

```
class AbstractVertexAction
{
public:
    virtual void DoAction(const Vertext &) = 0;
};
```

This approach might be the best one if the code of a typical action is complex.

Comment: Thanks. Many insights here. But how is returning a pointer any better than returning a set? After all, either choice has no impact on how I decide to implement the `Graph` object. What I mean is that I can easily just change the `map` into a `vector` and re-implement the `getAllVertices` function and user won't be affected.

Comment: I have never said to returns pointers so I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I meant iterator :p sorry, typo

Comment: If you returns iterators, then you don't have access to functions like `insert` and the code would not be able to assume that item are sorted or uniques... So the calling code knows less details about the implementation so there are less risk that the code depends on details it should not...

Comment: But the set has absolutely nothing to do with the implementation of the innards of the object. It's merely a message holder :P